# ASP.NET WebAPI slow responses at the initial phase

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task

I made an empty project referencing only a Web API and tweaked these simple APIs to see if there're any performance differences and any possible hangs on one of the async jobs.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Welcome")]
    public async Task<string> Welcome()
    {
        string r = await SlowMethod();
        return r;
    }

    public async Task<string> SlowMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return await Task.FromResult("data");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("WelcomeSync")]
    public string WelcomeSync()
    {
        string r = SlowSyncMethod();
        return r;
    }

    public string SlowSyncMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return "data";
    }
}
```

And I ran the API tests using jMeter with [this test plan](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lvdCbh8XQZxssLISdExirh925RVqkCSH). The result is pretty much the same in terms of throughput, but there's a noticeable difference in "Max" item in this result table from jMeter.

```
Label   Samples Average Min     Max     Std.Dev             Error%    Throughput    Received KB/sec     Sent KB/sec         Avg.Bytes

Async   100000  3193    3000    [32046] 1343.6219321793749  0.0 62.534550339062335  21.557320575868168  7.69468099875181    353.0    
Sync    100000  3003    3000    [3050]  3.523236520886259   0.0 66.54055014396047   23.458143165986066  8.447530779994983   361.0
```

**Max** is the millisecond unit by the way. Each APIs is supposed to take at least 3 seconds per a request as the result of `Thread.Sleep(3000);` But one of the requests, or some of them, took 32 seconds to be done.

Does this mean there was a hang on at least one async job? If there was, what's the culprit for the hang?

---

## UPDATED

I once suspected hanging behaviour on the async job, but it turned out that's not the case. Just changing the test order puts out the same result. **The first test will be always slow at the beginning of the test.** This was completely not related to async vs sync job whatsoever.

Anyway I tried to leave logs between the `SlowMethod();` using `Stopwatch` to see if there is actual hanging on the async method and soon I found out there's no hanging for sure on both async and sync APIs. The logs always print "It took 3 seconds".

```
2018-08-12 13:40:11 "Welcome async 'Welcome'. It took 3 seconds"
2018-08-12 13:40:14 "Welcome async 'Welcome'. It took 3 seconds"
2018-08-12 13:40:17 "Welcome async 'Welcome'. It took 3 seconds"
.
.
.
```

**What was late was the HTTP response itself**. And there was a certain, noticeable characteristic on the slowness.

- The performance starts to lose its pace shortly.
- It keeps slowing down until it reaches 30~40 seconds processing
- After that it starts to recover from the dragging performances.
- Eventually it keeps responding within 3 seconds till the end.

This is the logs that will help you picture better.

```
2018-08-04 04:48:50.030 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 3. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:50.030 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 3. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:50.030 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 9, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 3. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:50.030 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 10, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 3. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:50.632 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 4. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:51.637 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 5. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:52.631 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 6. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:52.968 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 6. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:52.969 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 6. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:52.969 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 6. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:52.973 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 6. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:53.631 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 7. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:53.637 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 7. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:54.631 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 8. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:54.640 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 8. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:55.633 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 9. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:55.635 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 9. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:55.975 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 9. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:55.976 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 9. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:55.976 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 9. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:55.979 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 9. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:56.633 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 10. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:56.636 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 10. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:48:56.642 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 10. The result was "data"
.
.
.
2018-08-04 04:49:04.647 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 18. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:04.650 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 18. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:04.994 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 18. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:04.994 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 18. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:04.998 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 18. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:04.999 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 18. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:05.633 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 19. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:05.636 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 19. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:05.640 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 19. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:05.643 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 19. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:05.646 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 19. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:05.652 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 19. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:06.633 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 20. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:06.638 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 20. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:06.641 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 20. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:06.643 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 20. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:06.647 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 20. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:06.655 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 20. The result was "data"
.
.
.
2018-08-04 04:49:15.634 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 28. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.639 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 28. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.644 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 28. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.648 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 28. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.652 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.653 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.655 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:15.665 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.635 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.638 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.647 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.650 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.669 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.669 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.669 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.670 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 10, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:16.673 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:17.014 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was 
2018-08-04 04:49:17.662 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 30. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:17.668 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:17.675 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:17.676 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.634 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.644 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 10, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.647 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.648 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 15, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.651 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 15, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.654 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 15, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.661 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 31. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.668 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.671 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:18.675 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.640 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.646 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 11, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.646 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.656 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.659 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 32. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.667 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.669 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.673 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 16, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.677 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 15, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:19.679 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 29. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:20.016 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 28. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:20.017 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 27. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 04:49:20.023 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 12, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 27. The result was "data"
.
.
.
2018-08-04 05:03:11.422 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 3. The result was "data"
2018-08-04 05:03:14.492 +09:00 [INF] CurrentThread 14, Context LeaseLifeTimeServiceProperty, Time passed 3. The result was "data"
```

`IIS recompilation`, `IIS application pool recycling`, and the `IIS idle timeout` setting were the prime suspects but it turned out that they have nothing to do with this problem. Seriously what's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The culprit

I finally opened up the underhood and tried to inspect every little details of what might cause this performance problem. The problem lies in `ThreadPool`. Well calling it a problem seems no longer right from now on.

The nature of the `ThreadPool` that doesn't like to create a new thread and increase the number of threads in its pool and has a tendency to fall back to the minimum number of threads whenever it is applicable is the behind scene of this phenomenon.

Well in my environment, the `ThreadPool` starts with 4 threads. I was able to realize this by calling.

```
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out int threadCount, out int portThread);
```

**Having only 4 threads** in the initial stage was simply not enough for dealing with the overwhelmingly incoming HTTP requests during the `jMeter` test. Consequently, letting `ThreadPool` maintain at least 200 threads so that it can start off with 200 threads solves this problem away.

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 4);
```

Now every requests will be processed within 3 seconds as expected to the end of the test. But manipulating the minimum number of threads in `ThreadPool` in a meaningless manner is not recommended because it might affect the performance in the application.

**This is the Caution from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netframework-4.7.2)**

> By default, the minimum number of threads is set to the number of processors on a system. You can use the SetMinThreads method to increase the minimum number of threads. However, unnecessarily increasing these values can cause performance problems. If too many tasks start at the same time, all of them might appear to be slow. In most cases, the thread pool will perform better with its own algorithm for allocating threads. Reducing the minimum to less than the number of processors can also hurt performance.

---

## **Easy solution without using `SetMinThreads`**

Using `Task.Delay(3000)`; instead of `Thread.Sleep(3000)` clears this problem away too. Since `Thread.Sleep(3000)` simply blocks the current thread, it may cause `ThreadPool` to create more threads. Actually, you can see this actually happen in the resource monitor.

This is `Task.Delay(3000);` version and I took this screenshot 1 min after the test has started. Only 59 threads created and the number **stays the same or below** during the test.

[image]

This is `Thread.Sleep(3000);` version and I took this at the same time. But iisexpress has spawned 116 threads and the number **keeps increasing** during the test.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While using `Thread.Sleep(3000);` in the sync test is ok, you will get a better representation using `Task.Delay` when faking long running async calls.

```
public async Task<string> SlowMethod() {
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    return "data";
}
```